# Irreducibility of $x_1^2+x_2^2+...+x_n^2$ in $\mathbb{C}[x_1,...,x_n]$

Tags: irreducible-polynomials

I wanted to know whether the polynomial function
$x_1^2+...+x_n^2 \in \mathbb{C}[x_1,...,x_n]$
is irreducible in $\mathbb{C}[x_1,...,x_n]$ for $3 \leq n$ ?

Comment: First thing that comes to mind is induction with Eisenstein's? I haven't checked this.

Comment: ok: correct me, if i`m wrong: so if i know that $x_1^2+...+x_{n-1}^2$ is irreducible and therefore prime. Then $f_n=f_{n-1}+x_n^2$ is irreducible because i can use $f_{n-1}$ as the prime element which is needed for the Eisenstein criterion?